# jquery autocomplete, passing JSON data from mysql query

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, json

Autocomplete function not working at all after entering text into form input. Checked the front end with a local array variable and it works, so it must be the way that I am passing data. There is no filter going on at the moment (just trying to see any suggestions), so I expect to see all the data in the suggest drop down.

For this url:

```
'/users/get_usernames'
```

This is my page output:

```
[{"label":"philip","value":"philip"},
 {"label":"sandford","value":"sandford"},
 {"label":"rona1918914615","value":"rona1918914615"},
 {"label":"rej1324558654","value":"rej1324558654"}]
```

My JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    $( "#to" ).autocomplete({
        source: '/users/get_usernames'
    });
});
```

My HTML includes:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

PHP from v_users_get_usernames.php:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($usernames as $username):

    $data[] = array(
        'label' => $username['user_name'],
        'value' => $username['user_name']
    );
endforeach;

// jQuery wants JSON data
echo json_encode($data);

flush();
```

Comment: "not working at all" is our favorite error message. Have you entered any text in the textbox? Autocomplete does not display all options when no text is entered.

Comment: Included the jquery-ui code?

For instance: 
`<!--Autocomplete scripts-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" /> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Comment: i have the jquery ui, and i have entered text

Comment: Try getting rid of the quotes on `"label"` and `"value"` that you return from `/users/get_usernames`

Comment: @ethorn10 how would i do that? just posted my php...

Comment: You could send the `Content-Type` header down with your JSON. Just to enforce it being interpreted properly on the other end. Do you have firebug or something that can debug the results of typing `r` in your textbox?  To send the header, add this above your `echo`... `header("Content-Type: application/json");`

Comment: @ethorn10 still nothing after passing the content-type. at least in chrome console, no visible error messages.

Comment: @compguy24 can you create a jsfiddle for us? That should help dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your dom element wasn't ready when calling `autocomplete`.

Ensure you have this on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  //this ensures dom is ready
   $( "#to" ).autocomplete({
       source: '/users/get_usernames'
   });
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Ok. Are you sure your `#to` input exists? could you do this?: `alert($( "#to" ).length)` and this: `alert($( "#to" ).autocomplete)` and tell me what happens?

Comment: length = 1, second alert = "function (a){var r="string"==typeof a,h=s.call(arguments,1),l=this;return a=!r&&h.length?t.widget.extend.apply(null,[a].concat(h)):a,r?this.each(function(){var s,n=t.data(this,o);return n?t.isFunction(n[a])&&"_"!==a.charAt(0)?(s=n[a].apply(n,h),s!==n&&s!==e?(l=s&&s.jquery?l.pushStack(s.get()):s,!1):e):t.error("no such method '"+a+"' for "+i+" widget instance"):t.error("cannot call methods on "+i+" prior to initialization; "+"attempted to call method '"+a+"'")}):this.each(function(){var e=t.data(this,o);e?e.option(a||{})._init():t.data(this,o,new n(a,this))}),l}"